# Updating a vector outside the loop in map(), using R

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I have the following simple vector:

```
a = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

and I would like to obtain a vector (b) such that for each indicator x in a, if a[x] is 1, we let it as is, and if it is 0, we compute a[x-1] + 1, until the next 1:

```
b = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5)
```

I tried using map():

```
map(
  .x = seq(1,(length(a))),
  .f = function(x) {
    a[x] = ifelse(a[x]==1, a[x], a[x-1]+1)
    a})
```

Obviously this does not work because map does not update the a vector. How can I do this using map(). Is it even possible to update a something outside map() ?

Comment: My solution to your previous question, uses `purrr::reduce`, which may correspond to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just change it to use the superassignment operator `<<-`, the way you attempted it does in fact work.

```
a = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

map(
  .x = seq(1,(length(a))),
  .f = function(x) {
    a[x] <<- ifelse(a[x]==1, a[x], a[x-1]+1)
    a})
a

#> [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what the superassignment does?

Comment: It's actually called 'scoping assignment' if you wanna make research yourself

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution close to what you're looking (i.e. that would mimic a `for loop`) for is `purrr::accumulate`.

```r
accumulate(1:8, .f = ~ ifelse(a[.y] == 1, 1, .x + 1))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I did not know the accumulate function, very nice. Yet I think the conceptual question remains: how can I update an outside object in map?

Comment: Can you explaine what is the .y argument? from ?accumulate i see only .x

Comment: This is indeed not well documented: .y is the value in the list, .x is the previous value. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/277).